# How to customized an input component from another component?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, styled-components

For this input component, I want to make it as a basic component for other components.

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const TextField: React.FC<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (
  props
) => {
  return (
    <Input type="text" {...props} />
  );
};

const Input = styled.input`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    width: 100%;
    color: ${theme.color.text};
  `}
`;
```

This is a customized one and add some styles:

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { TextField } from "~/components";

export type ProductFieldProps = {
  name: string;
  value?: string;
};

type ProductFieldTypeProps = {
  textAlign: string;
};

export const ProductField: React.FC<ProductFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  value,
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledTextField textAlign="center">
      <TextField name={name} value={value} />
    </StyledTextField>
  );
};

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  ${({ theme }) => css<ProductFieldTypeProps>`
    &:hover {
      border-color: ${theme.color.hover};
    }
  `}
`;
```

When use the new component ProductField,

```
# pages/index.tsx
import { ProductField } from "~/components";

...
return {
  <>
    <ProductField name="aaa" value="bbb" />
  </>
}
```

I got a server error:

> Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

How to set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `styled-components` to style your Input component.

You can see on this line that you are applying styles to the `TextField` component:

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)
```

And yet in the new `ProductField` component you import both, the styled version and the original one and nest them in each other:

```
    <StyledTextField textAlign="center">
      <TextField name={name} value={value} />
    </StyledTextField>
```

This essentially means you are nesting two input field into each other, which is not allowed and hence the error:

> Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

One way to approach this is to simply remove the nested `TextField` like so, and apply all the props to the styled one instead:

```
<StyledTextField textAlign="center" name={name} value={value} />
```

Another solution would be to just export and use the styled version directly because the additional wrapper seems redundant.

[More info on how to style custom components with styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)